# "Йошкін кот" - це "Йосип на кобилі"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Знайшла цікаву інформацію у [Блозі відомого журналіста](https://vlyt.livejournal.com/65936.html), що російське "*Ёшкин кот*" (ключова фраза у фільмі "Любовь и голуби") українською буде "*Йосип на кобилі*". Чи справді так звучить український відповідник цього словосполучення? У [російсько-українських словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/) не знайшла відповіді.

Comment: Якщо почитати блог, то автор навпаки критично відноситься до цього "перекладу". "Йошкін кот" це евфемізм, головна ціль якого - почати фразу з довгого "Йо". Якщо дія проходить в українському селі - таким евфемізмом цілком можливо буде "Йосип на кобилі", але у радянському сеттінгу такий переклад викликає (принаймні у автора блога) подив, так само якби таку фразу вклали в уста техаського рейнджера.

Answer (score 2):

Спершу подивимося, що ж таке "[йошкін кот](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82)":

> Фразеологізм. Використовується як вигук.

І його значення:

> вживається для того, щоб висловити досаду, сильне здивування, подив
>   або іншу емоцію.

Тепер перейдемо до фразеологізму "Йосип на кобилі". Наскільки мені відомо - це також вигук, який вживається, щоб висловити сильне здивування, досаду та подив:

> Та **Йосип на кобилі**! - каже вона і йде відчиняти сама, з кожним кроком дедалі сильніше дратуючись (Стівен Кінг "Кінець зміни").

Або ж ще також процитую одного користувача з цього [форуму](http://forum.meta.ua/topic/t/48364.html):

> По-моєму, це просто нестача культури. Коли де тільки можна вставляють
>   відоме (хоч його нема у словнику) слово з 3 букв у різних комбінаціях
>   і чиюсь матір у незручному для неї положенні - які тут негаразди у
>   суспільстві? А щоб емоційно виразитися, краще сказати: "Чорт візьми!",
>   "**Йосип на кобилі!**", "Японська хата!" або щось схоже. Справді, без
>   таких матюків, від яких вуха в"януть, можна прекрасно обійтися. І ще й
>   набагато краще!

Тобто бачимо, що фразеологізми між собою схожі. Тому я гадаю, що замінити фразеологізм "йошкін кот" "Йосипом на кобилі" можна.

Однак, не все так просто! В Інтернеті це питання викликало цілу бурю різних думок. Чому? Більше про це я дізнався на цьому форумі. Серед аргументів чому не варто перекладати фразеологізм "йошкін кот" були:

- "*Рідковживані вислови краще перекладати тупо і в лоб. Написали би "Йошкин кіт", і ні у кого би це не викликало би ніяких дурносміхств*". І справді, [можливий](http://nashe-chtivo.ru/fo4.html) дослівний переклад (калькування) фразеологічних одиниць (хоч тут ідеться про переклад з англіської на українську, однак ці самі правила ми можемо застосувати для перекладу з росіської на українську, [приклад](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%EA%EE%F2&submit=%D8%F3%EA%E0%F2%E8)). Проте, я не впевнений, що "йошкін кіт" - це "рідковживаний вислів".
- "*Подібний вислів - евфемізм, не більше. Там немає значення, просто слово-паразит. Зі "звучанням" типу матюка. Значить будь-який "замінник" матюка годиться*". Знову ж таки, згідно до цитати із першого форуму вигук "Йосип на кобилі" може вживатися як "замінник матюка" (тобто є ефемізмом), і також може бути "словом-паразитом".
- Тут же пропонується "влучніший варіант" перекладу - "[Йоханий бабай!](http://myslovo.com/?dictionary=%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9)". Це теж ефемізм, сленг, і також [виражає досаду](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53401/374628.html), подив тощо. Тому гадаю, що він також може бути хорошим замінником "йошкіного кота".

Отож, особисто я не розумію, чому не можна перекласти "йошкін кот" як "йосип на кобилі". Проте, зробимо висновок, що можна скалькувати і сказати "йошкін кіт" або ж сказати "йоханий бабай", або ж іще один вигук - "[Капець](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/vidpovidi/shho-oznachaye-slovo-kapec/)!".