# Що означають ці фразеологізми про Йосипа

Tags: фразеологізми

Після запитання [“Йошкін кот” - це “Йосип на кобилі”?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3540/9) я поцікавився значенням цього фразеологізму. Я так розумію, що Йосип, то Сталін, але яке значення мають ці фразеологізми, частину з яких я знайшов на [теревенях](http://tereveni.org/topic/15385/) (див. другу сторінку):

- Йосип на кобилі
- Йосип за пеньком
- Йосип босий
- Йосип драний

Приклад вживання із життя:

[image]

Comment: Я не згоден з поширенням подібних фразеологізмів.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko це сайт здебільшого не про мовну політику, а про дійсне функціонування української мови сьогодні й не тільки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Швидше за все ці фразеологізми є цензурним замінником/продовженням (евфемізмом) для обсценного виразу "йоб твою/його мать".

Аналогічну природу мають [російські "йолки-палки"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8), [йо-майо](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91) і їм подібні вирази.
Ця ж сама версія викладена у відповіді на згадане вами запитання за посиланням.

Тобто, ніякого стосунку ні до якого реального Йосипа вони не мають. Так само як і не має якогось особливого значення все, що йде після цього слова.