# Переклад російського слова "ё-моё"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно зробити переклад російського слова "ё-моё"?

> [ё-моё](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91) - выражает досаду или удивление.

[Google перекладач](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/uk/%D1%91-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91) подає як "йо-майо"

Проте в словниках такого слова немає.

Comment: Часто чув варіант "Отакої".

Comment: «О це так!» може допомогти

Comment: @Enguroo думаю, радше "оце так".

Answer (score 2):

Читаємо про [етимологію вигуку](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91#%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) "ё-моё":

> Створено за ефімістичною моделлю "перший звук, склад нецензурного
>   слова чи вислову з неочікуваним продовженням". За цією ж моделлю було
>   створено вислови йолки-палки, йошкін кіт

І саме ж значення у нього таке як у йошкіного кота (а на цю тему вже є схоже [питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96)). І тому так само як з йошкіним котом, ми можемо перекласти "ё-моё" як "Йосип на кобилі", "Йоханий бабай", "Капець!" тощо.